# invalid request(unexpected EOF) - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url

Hi I'm trying to load in parsely.css with the following laravel code. The parsley file is in the public folder of the application and when i render the page i get an error message - invalid request(unexpected EOF).

```
@section('stylesheets')

{!! Html::style('public/css/parsley.css')!!}

@stop
```

View is posts/create.blade.php:

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', '| Create New Post')

@section('stylesheets')

{!! Html::style('public/css/parsley.css') !!}

@stop

@section('content')

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset2">

        <h1>Create New Post</h1>
        <hr>

        {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'posts.store')) !!}

            {{Form::label('title', 'Title:')}}

            {{Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}

            {{Form::label('body', "Post Body:")}}

            {{Form::textarea('body', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}

            {{Form::submit('Create Post', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top:20px;'))}}

        {!! Form::close() !!}

    </div>

</div>

@endsection
```

======================================= below is the code that appears in the files in the storage -> framework -> views

```
<?php $__env->startSection('title', '| Create New Post'); ?>

<?php $__env->startSection('stylesheets'); ?>

<?php echo Html::style('public/css/parsley.css'); ?>


<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset2">

        <h1>Create New Post</h1>
        <hr>

        <?php echo Form::open(array('route' => 'posts.store')); ?>


            <?php echo e(Form::label('title', 'Title:')); ?>


            <?php echo e(Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))); ?>


            <?php echo e(Form::label('body', "Post Body:")); ?>


            <?php echo e(Form::textarea('body', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))); ?>


            <?php echo e(Form::submit('Create Post', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top:20px;'))); ?>


        <?php echo Form::close(); ?>


    </div>

</div>

<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>


<?php echo $__env->make('main', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this error because you didn't use a closing tag like `@endforeach`, `@endif`, `@endsection` etc somewhere.

Also, you're using wrong syntax, it should be:

```
{!! Html::style('public/css/parsley.css') !!}
```

Comment: @steven if you can't find the cause of the error by yourself and want some help, you should post the view here. Only after that we'll be able to help you.

Comment: @steven are you sure you've shown the view which causes the error? Also, when you see the error message, it shows rendered view also with name like `8cfh733h....22c.php`. Please post it too.

Comment: Im running the php artisan serve command to run the server and it brings up this error in the terminal.

Comment: @steven if you don't see full error message, you can find it in `storage/logs/laravel.log` file.

Comment: I can't even add a normal html link url to this file <link href="../../../public/css/parsley.css" rel="stylesheet"> When i use the console i get this link cannot be found.

Comment: I'm getting no error message in the log. Just in the terminal when i run php artisan serve command

Comment: @steven another way is to delete all rendered views from `storage/framework/views`, load the page again and post here contents of the only generated file from the same directory.

Comment: Forget that I still am :/

Comment: I fixed it using:
<link href="{{ URL::to('public/css/parsley.css') }}">

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `@stop` not `@endsection` on the end of the section. Also you can specify layout of the section by `@exdends('your.layout.file')`

Comment: Also you need to remove 1 set of curly braces like this: `{!! Html::style('public/css/parsley.css')!!}`